# Add a class to an element if a variable is greater than x in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an element with the id `counter`

I also have a javascript variable called `abacus`

When the value of abacus is greater than *x* - I wish to add a CSS class to the element with the id `counter

```js
var abacus = 8

  if (abacus > 5) {
    document.getElementById("counter");
    element.classList.add("greater");
  }

  else {
    document.getElementById("counter");
    element.classList.add("less");
  }
```

```html
<div id="counter">
</div>
```

When I run this code though, the css class is not applied.

Comment: What's `element`? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: Okay, so... go for it.  Or is there a question here?

Comment: you prob ment `var element = document.getElementById("counter");`, voting as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check_number(){
   var abacus = 8
   var num = document.getElementById("num").value
   if (abacus > num) {
      var element = document.getElementById("counter");
      element.classList.add("blackBG");
   }

   else {
       var element = document.getElementById("counter");
       element.classList.remove("blackBG");
   }
}
```

```css
.blackBG {
        background-color:#c79d9d;
 }
```

```html
<div id="counter">
    some text
</div>
  
<input type="text" id="num">
<button onclick="check_number()">click </button>
```

Comment: you should use :  var element = document.getElementById("counter");  what was wrong in your code was that : you forget "var element =" part

Answer (score 0):

when you access the element you either need to assign it to a variable or chain the additional js to it.

```js
var abacus = 8

  if (abacus > 5) {
    document.getElementById("counter").classList.add("greater");
  }

  else {
    document.getElementById("counter").classList.add("less");
  }
```

```html
<div id="counter">
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation instead of a code dump is always more useful